# convert milliseconds column to seconds in a csv file

Tags: linux, date, time

I have a large tab separated file without headers like this:

```
Tue Jun 09 18:06:53 GMT 2020    1591726013187
Tue Jun 09 18:20:31 GMT 2020    1591726831779
Tue Jun 09 18:09:01 GMT 2020    1591726141456
```

I am trying to convert the 2nd column to seconds from milliseconds, and seems havinng some issues. This is what I am using:

```
awk '{print strftime("%c", ( $2 + 500 ) / 1000 )}' file.tsv
```

Also not sure if using awk is the most efficient way given the size of the file. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused.  The second column (from the perspective of your awk invocation, anyway) is "Jun" .... how do want to represent that as milliseconds?

Comment: @tink The firs column is the date (Tue Jun 09 18:06:53 GMT 2020) and the second columns is the milliseconds.

Comment: If your file is tab-delimited, you need to run `awk -F '\t'`

Comment: No, awk uses ANY whitesepace as separator, your second column is "Jun"

Comment: Otherwise, please add to your question a sample output from your `awk` script. _Having some issues_ doesn't really tell us what's wrong, so that we can help you.

Comment: If your file has a mix of tabs and space characters, we're in the dark. In that case, you can use `cat -T` to show the tabs.

Comment: I'm very confused. The value of the milliseconds on the right is precisely the same as the date shown on the left anyway, in all 3 cases. Just clip off the last field.

Comment: why don't you just delete the last 3 digits?

Answer (score 1):

I still think that your question is worded very poorly, but given your comments I assume you're after *this*:

```
$ echo -e  "Tue Jun 09 18:20:31 GMT 2020\t1591726831779" | awk  -F"\t" '{printf "%s\t%u\n",  $1, ($2+500)/1000 }'
Tue Jun 09 18:20:31 GMT 2020    1591726832
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decide you don't care about rounding but you can just truncate the millisecond digits, you could just

```bsh
sed 's/...$//' file
```

use `sed -i` to overwrite the original contents.